# Clearing redux store on logout in react native cause error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I have a react native app setup with redux when the user logs out of their account I want to be able to clear the redux store for security reasons.
But this causes an error as some components are already mounted and are using data from the redux store, is there a proper way to do this?

The workaround I am current using is checking the redux store at the start of every component is the store is empty (i.e. values are null) then the component returns null

Comment: Your store should have an initial state (for example: user not logged in). I would suggest to dispatch a reset action when the user logs out and reset the store the initial state.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clearing the reduxStore values you can just change value back to its initialState.

For Example :-

```
const initialState = {
loggedIn: false,
data: {}
}

const yourReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RESET_STATE: 
    return {
      initialState
    }
}
```

Comment: i am setting the the store back to the initial state itself, sorry for the misunderstanding The problem occurs when I am try to refer to a value with the state.
For example: when something like this is present in a component data.name after data is set to initial state data.name becomes null causing the component to throw an error

Comment: 1. for this kind of situation always code in such a way that it does not break.                  
    for eg :- for data.name  const  { name = '' } = data

Comment: we could do that but I wanted to know is there any way to tell react to unmount the components before clearing the store?

Comment: let's say you have AuthScreen where you ask for Login and as user Logs in you get all data and you go Next to App Screen where you use that data. Now in this situation if you want to clear Data as user Logout it is better do it when in componentWIllUnmount of AppScreen or componentDidMount of AuthScreen. Your Navigation handles the calling of react activity lifecycle so if you want to unMount you need to navigate Out of the Screen.